# I'm trying to implement event tracking in to a sign in buttom from eventbrite

Tags: javascript, html, css, eventbrite

I'm trying to use this following code on my page to track events from eventbrite, but my knowledge in HTML is really basic.

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:left;" >
<iframe  src="//eventbrite.com.br/tickets-external?eid=22222454961&ref=etckt" 
frameborder="0" height="350" width="100%" vspace="0" hspace="0" marginheight="5" 
marginwidth="5" scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
<div style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial; font-size:10px; padding:5px 0 5px; margin:2px; width:100%; text-align:left;" >
   <a class="powered-by-eb" style="color: #dddddd; text-decoration: none;" 
       onClick=”ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘Inscrição SP’, ‘Click’, ‘Security Leaders’);” target="_blank" href="http://www.eventbrite.com.br/r/etckt">Com tecnologia Eventbrite</a>
</div>
</div>
```